# Specific Field change using ngGridEventEndCellEdit in ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I have been facing a problem with `ngGridEventEndCellEdit` in `ng-grid` module.

My purpose is when i change a cell in ng-grid i call a method from my service and that method returns some data via an ajax request. My code works fine. But the only problem is that when i change any cell or field it calls the service method.

How i check that a specific cell is edit???

Follow is my code snippet...

```
$scope.$on('ngGridEventEndCellEdit', function (data) {
            console.log(data.targetScope.row);
            costsheetCrudService.getItemByItemCode(data.targetScope.row.entity.ItemCode).then(function (res) {
                data.targetScope.row.entity.ItemDescription = res.data.ItemDescription;
                data.targetScope.row.entity.ItemCategory = res.data.ItemCategoryName;
                data.targetScope.row.entity.ItemID = res.data.ItemID;
                data.targetScope.row.entity.ItemCategoryID = res.data.ItemCategoryID;
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can't you use the `data` variable to check for the specific cell ? Something like : `if(data.targetScope.col.index === X) {}` or `if(data.targetScope.row.entity.something === something else) {}`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation on templating](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating) :

> When editing a cell, the ng-cell-has-focus directive will broadcast a message named **ngGridEventStartCellEdit** to let all children know that
>   you can now give yourself focus. When the editable cell template is
>   done with editing (usually on a blur event) you need to emit
>   **ngGridEventEndCellEdit** to let ng-cell-has-focus know that you are done
>   editing and it will then show the non-editable cell template. The
>   reasoning for this is (good quote): "Now I can wrap my input elements
>   in divs/spans, whatever and control exactly what element's blur
>   triggers the end edit" - @swalters.
>
> If you search for the 'ngInput' directive in ng-rgid's source code,
>   you will find that that is exactly what this directive implements for
>   input elements. **So if you need to create your own 'cell editor', you
>   could create your own directive that would listen to and emit the
>   right events, to make your component work as expected.**

An example (used for ng-input directive):

```
scope.$on( 'ngGridEventStartCellEdit', function () {
  elm.focus(); 
}); //focus the input element on 'start cell edit'

angular.element( elm ).bind( 'blur', function () {
  scope.$emit( 'ngGridEventEndCellEdit' );
}); //when leaving the input element, emit the 'end cell edit' event
```

Otherwise, you can add logic inside your controller, when the event is emitted :

```
if(data.targetScope.col.index === X) {}
if(data.targetScope.row.rowIndex === X) {}
if(data.targetScope.row.entity.something === something else) {}.
```